# Moving from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I just moved form the Android Eclipse plugin to Android studio for my new app, and I feel like Android Studio is missing a few Eclipse features that I frequently used, or at least I can't find them.

So where is the auto-import feature (ctrl-shift-o) and the code format feature (ctrl-shift-f) in Android Studio? I use these features a lot and I feel lost in Android Studio.

Comment: Go to settings-> keymap and here you can find all shortcuts.

Comment: You will quickly see that Android Studio is 10 time more powerful than Eclipse. You will never return back to Eclipse :). And yes, check keymap shortcuts to find all features. You can also use Canary channel Android Studio which is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me very little time to get used to Android Studio.  A few more crashes than I am used to, but everything is so much more geared towards development for Android.

Auto-import: File -> Settings (or Ctrl+Alt+S) -> Editor -> Auto Import and select the options you need.  (I have Insert Imports on Paste = All; Optimize imports on the fly = Yes; Add unambigious imports on the fly = Yes).

To format code, it's CTRL + ALT + L (it's different on a Mac, but you can look for this in the Keymap section of the settings).

Comment: Thank you. Not as fluid as eclipse but it will work.